# Using C++ objects from C

Tags: c++, c, object

I would like to use C/C++ mixed code. I also need access to C++ object member variables from C code.

It works (at least in gcc), that I pass pointer to the object and handle it as a `struct`.

From C++:

```
class MyData {
  ...
};
```

From C:

```
struct MyData {
  ...
};
```

*(Of course, I do not duplicate code in the final header file)*

1, I am not sure that this would work using any of the compilers. Is there any reasons why I should not rely on this?

2, If `MyData` class has virtual member functions, this would not work, but a pointer to the first member variable could solve the problem. Is this safe, or may I get into trouble with this?

Comment: Lots of things seem to work but are illegal in C/C++. The real question is why you want to mix the languages that needs acess to objects from one language from the othere?

Comment: There's no such thing as C/C++. There's C++ code that happens to be legal C and vice-versa. *Often* it even has the same semantics, but there are examples where semantics change! As with every language interop, use foreign-functiom-interfaces (FFI). C++ can expose a C FFI via extern-C. That's the only right way to do that.

Comment: The main code is written in C. New, complex algorithms has to be implemented, so a higher abstraction level language would be surely a better choice. Therefore, C++ will be used for these issues. C  FFI is a trivial solution, but I hoped, there may be a more efficient  way to access member variables (i.e. without calling "helper" functions). But, there isn't any :(

Comment: According to the followings, accessing of member data w/o virtual functions and base classes should work: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp#get-cpp-data-members-from-c

Answer (score 3):

The first answer already suggested to define a "glue type" that is legal in both C and C++. It is, however, important to emphasize that it is necessary but not sufficient. A more precise answer would be that you need to define *the same type* that has *the same binary layout*.

To clarify:

```
struct my_struct {
    int a;
    bool b;
};
```

can have wildly different binary representations depending on the alignment of `my_struct` (what's the `sizeof` of `my_struct` when the alignment 16 bits and 32 bits?). In this case not only the members are important, but *what's between the members*, i.e., the padding bits.

This is why the pointer to the first member will simply not be enough to have portable code.

The most portable approach would be to define a higher level API, to distill the essence of what you are doing and have functions that can be parameterized via trivial types, i.e., ints, chars, floats.

Comment: This is only true if you're going to cross toolchain boundaries. If you're compiling both the C and C++ parts in the same toolchain as part of the same project/build, you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Uh, no, you can't do that. If you compile a .c file that happens to be legal C++ as well with g++, you aren't mixing C and C++: You are simply writing C++. There's no mixing of these languages.

Comment: @larkey Compile a .c, then compile a .cpp, then link them together. We do it all the time. It's called interop.

Comment: You can only do that if you use C FFI, ie. extern-C. Otherwise this won't work, oftentimes. `int foo(void)` usually emits different different symbols on C and C++ and structures can work differently as well.

Answer (score 3):

The classic approach is that your C++ code exposes flat C functions for accessing instances of your class.  And marks these functions as `extern "C"`.

Example `mydata.h`

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

#ifdef __cplusplus

class MyData
{
public:
    MyData();
    void SetX(int val);
    int GetX();
private:
    int _x;
};

#endif

typedef void* MYDATA;


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    MYDATA MyData_new();
    void MyData_delete(MYDATA md);
    void MyData_SetX(MYDATA md, int x);
    int MyData_GetX(MYDATA md);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif


#endif
```

Then in `mydata.cpp`

```
#include "mydata.h"

MyData::MyData() : _x(0)
{
}

int MyData::GetX()
{
    return _x;
}

void MyData::SetX(int val)
{
    _x = val;
}

extern "C"  MYDATA MyData_new()
{
    return new MyData();
}

extern "C" void MyData_Delete(MYDATA foo)
{
    auto pFoo = reinterpret_cast<MyData*>(foo);
    delete pFoo;
}

extern "C" void MyData_SetX(MYDATA foo, int x)
{
    auto pFoo = reinterpret_cast<MyData*>(foo);
    pFoo->SetX(x);
}

extern "C" int MyData_GetX(MYDATA foo)
{
    auto pFoo = reinterpret_cast<MyData*>(foo);
    return pFoo->GetX();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is to write a C interface API for your C++ code.

I would make this by using a separate header and a separate .cpp file. In the header define an API that **does not** include the C++ header. That's a rookie mistake. This header has to stand alone as a C version of your code.

I would not expose any kind of `struct`. If you have to, have functions that return pointers to members. Then the C code can directly read and write to the pointer. Better yet are functions to explicitly get and set member values.

You can use a `void*` or use a `struct` forward declaration for your object type.

Then build C functions to construct, destruct, copy, and all member functions which take a pointer to `this` as a parameter. You can't call it `this` because that conflicts with C++, so use `self` or something. Constructors and copy constructors obviously don't take `this`, they return a pointer to a new object.

Put all of these functions in the header inside an `extern "C" { }` block with ifdef guards.

So here's an example I played with:

---

```
// c-cpp-string-api.cpp

#include "c-cpp-string-api.h"
#include <string>

namespace {
static inline struct cppstring *to_c(std::string *p) {
  return reinterpret_cast<cppstring *>(p);
}

static inline std::string *from_c(struct cppstring *p) {
  return reinterpret_cast<std::string *>(p);
}
} // namespace

struct cppstring *cppstring_construct(const char *str) {
  return to_c(new std::string(str));
}

cppstring *cppstring_copy(cppstring *str) {
  return to_c(new std::string(*from_c(str)));
}

void cppstring_destruct(cppstring *str) { delete from_c(str); }

const char *cppstring_cstr(cppstring *str) { return from_c(str)->c_str(); }
```

---

```
// c-cpp-string-api.h

#pragma once

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

struct cppstring;

struct cppstring *cppstring_construct(const char *str);
struct cppstring *cppstring_copy(struct cppstring *str);
void cppstring_destruct(struct cppstring *str);

const char *cppstring_cstr(struct cppstring *str);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

---

```
// c-cpp-string-api-test.c

#include "c-cpp-string-api.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc < 2)
    return 1;

  struct cppstring *p1 = cppstring_construct(argv[1]);
  struct cppstring *p2 = cppstring_copy(p1);

  printf("value of string is %s and %s\n", cppstring_cstr(p1),
         cppstring_cstr(p2));

  cppstring_destruct(p2);
  cppstring_destruct(p1);
  return 0;
}
```

---

```
# Makefile

LTOFLAGS += -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects
OPTFLAGS += -O3 -march=native $(LTOFLAGS)
FLAGS += -Wall -W -pedantic -g $(OPTFLAGS) -MMD $(EXTRA)
FLAGS += -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong
CFLAGS = $(FLAGS) -std=c11
CXXFLAGS = $(FLAGS) -std=c++17
LDFLAGS += $(LTOFLAGS)

c-cpp-string-api-test: c-cpp-string-api.o c-cpp-string-api-test.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@

-include *.d

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.d c-cpp-string-api-test

.PHONY: clean
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a class that is legal in both C and C++:

```
struct MyData {
    int member;
};
```

You can use this class/struct definition in both languages and pass instances of it back and forth.

If class has C++ features such as member functions, bases, non-trivial members etc. then you can use it in C only through an opaque pointer, which won't allow you to access members.

Comment: For a bonus point, add that the OP's attempt has UB as the duplicate defs don't use the same set of tokens